# Разместить запись на стену

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу сделать кнопку "разместить сообщение в вк", создал приложение сайт, по примерам сделал небольшой код, но не получается нормально работать с ним. После нажатия на "Разместить" окно с подтверждением появляется раз через раз и вообще не совсем понятно по каким условиям. Единственное что заметил, если после строчки VK.Auth.login поставить алерт, окно с подтверждением разместить запись на стене появляется всегда. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://vkontakte.ru/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> VK.init({apiId: 7777, onlyWidgets: true}); </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function authInfo(response) {
        if (!response.session) {
            alert('Необходимо войти с помощью ВКонтакте.');
            return false;
        }

        VK.Api.call('wall.post', {
            message: 'test text ',
            }, function(r) {    
                if (r.error) {
                    console.log(r.error);
                    if (r.error.error_code == 10007) {
                        alert('Для участия в акции необходимо разместить запись на стене.');
                    }               
                    if (r.error.error_code == 20) {
                        alert('Произошла неизвестная ошибка, пожалуйста повторите еще раз.');
                    }               
                    if (r.error.error_code == 14) {
                        alert('Произошла неизвестная ошибка, повторите поже.');                 
                    }               
                    return false;
                }           
                alert('Успешно размещено!');
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#join').click(function() {

            VK.Auth.login(authInfo,1);
           // alert(1);
        });
    });

</script>

<a href="#" id="join">Разместить</a>
```

---

Вообще, даже пример предоставленный в примере документации http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=VK.Auth работает как то не правильно.

```
        //  alert('ok');

VK.Auth.login(function(response) {

  if (response.session) {
    /* Пользователь успешно авторизовался */
    alert(1);
    if (response.settings) {
      /* Выбранные настройки доступа пользователя, если они были запрошены */
      alert(2);
    }
  } else {
    /* Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации */
    alert(3);
  }
});
```

Алертов никаких не выводит, но опять же, если перед этим вывести что то, например alert('ok') то один из алеротов уже вылетит. Что я не правильно делаю ?

---

Рано радовался, выяснилось еще кое что, пример выше работает нормально во всех браузерах кроме firefox, версия в которой проверял - 16.0.1.

Comment: Смотрите JavaScript консоль в вашем браузере. Возможно, там появляются сообщения об ошибках во время работы скрипта — поможет разобраться.

Comment: Смотрел, никаких ошибок нет

Comment: >повторите поже.

Answer (score 2):

Метод [`wall.post()`](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.post) можно вызывать только из Desktop, iframe и Flash приложений.

Comment: Думаю вы не совсем правы, во 1 - в документации в описание Open API методов есть ссылка на этот метод. Во 2, я же как то вызывал его и постил на стену, другое дело что это срабатывало через раз как то.

Думаю проблема кроется в VK.Auth.login, можно просто без него в onClick вызвать wall.post() и он будет вызываться, но тогда если не пользователь не будет автоматизирован в вк он не поймет в чем дело и не будет той красивой формы с логином и паролем...

Comment: Смотрите еще обновленный мой пост...

Comment: @gera, Вы не правы. @Sergiks сказал всё правильно - ошибка в том, что метода (я даже уточню) может вызываться только из Desktop. Flash должен запросить разрешения на размещение, iframe не может размещать.

Comment: Это не iframe приложение, это сайт. Смотрите, тут http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Open_API если перейти по ссылке "все текущие методы" можно будет найти wall.post(). И еще раз повторюсь, если его НЕЛЬЗЯ использовать то как тогда так получилось что Я ПОСТИЛ на свою стену сообщение ?

Comment: @gera, я не могу посмотреть - прокси на работе на такие вещи плохо реагирует и режет ;), но я точно знаю что это прерогатива Desktop приложений.

Comment: Все, решил проблему сам, проблема была с инициализацией. onlyWidgets: true был лишним параметром, а вы говорите нельзя, нельзя :)

Comment: Я тут случайно пробегал мимо. Странно, когда люди плюсуют человека, не разобравшись в вопросе.

wall.post МОЖНО вызывать с сайта. В документации ясно написано, что wall.post нельзя вызывать с сайта через auth 2.0. А через open api по прежнему можно, и даже спустя 4 года.

И даже учитывая то, что в openapi.js
view-source:http://vk.com/js/api/openapi.js
там, где указаны права (строки 364-372 на данный момент) отсутствует wall, код VK.Auth.login(authInfo,'8192') прекрасно работает